# When to use DomainObjectCollection and NamedDomainObjectCollection in Gradle?

Tags: collections, gradle

When and in what circumstances can we use DomainObjectCollection and NamedDomainObjectCollection? Can you give me some examples?

From documentation I understand that they implements  `java.util.Collection` and

> A **DomainObjectCollection** is a specialised *Collection* that adds the
>   ability to modification
>   notifications and *live* filtered sub collections.

So they are JavaCollections that support "liveness". But how can I instantiated object from such type?

Through `project` object or how? I saw that there are DefaultNamedDomainObjectList classes which implements NamedDomainObjectList interface for example, but they are internal classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only `NamedDomainObjectContainer`s can be instantiated via a public API (`project.container()`).

Answer (score -1):

gradle 5

```
new DefaultNamedDomainObjectList(
        MyNamedClass.class,
        new Instantiator() {
            @Override
            def <T> T newInstance(Class<? extends T> aClass, Object... objects) throws ObjectInstantiationException {
                project.objects.newInstance(aClass, objects)
            }
        },
        new DynamicPropertyNamer())
```

gradle 6

```
project.objects.namedDomainObjectList(MyNamedClass.class);
```